# Calculating the radius of convergence for Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis

$$g(z)=\dfrac {\sin z-z+\dfrac{z^{3}}{6}}{\cos z-1}$$
What is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $g$ centered at 0.

My thought was to use the Cauchy-Hadamard formula to calculate it. But I don't know how to expand the $g(x)$ into power series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Radius_of_convergence_in_complex_analysis) it is stated that

> The radius of convergence of a power series $f$ centered on a point $a$ is equal to the distance from $a$ to the nearest point where $f$ cannot be defined in a way that makes it holomorphic.

This can be proven using [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula).

Since the closest non-removable singularity of $g$ to $z=0$ is $z=2\pi$, the radius of convergence should be $2\pi$.